# Simple Jquery slider, do not want to use plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslider

I have the following code, I have implemented something like this so far, but I want to add "NEXT" "PREV" functionality to this, for which I need suggesstion.

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="wrap"> 
<div class="panel">Panel1</div> 
<div class="panel">Panel2</div> 
<div class="panel">Panel3</div>
</div>

<div class="previous">This need Implementation</div>
<div class="next">This need Implementation</div>

</div>

<div class="nav">

<ul>
<li> panel1</li>
<li> panel2</li>
<li> panel3</li>
<ul>

</div>


$(document).ready(function () {

$(".wrap .panel:not(.active)").fadeOut();
$(".wrap .panel:first(.active)").fadeIn();

$(".nav ul li").click(function (event) {

$(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');

$(".wrap .panel").stop(true, true).fadeOut().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();

});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to store the index of the current pane displayed

```
var currentIndex = 0;// store current pane index displayed
var ePanes = $('#slider .panel');// store panes collection
function showPane(index){// generic showPane
    // hide current pane
    ePanes.eq(currentIndex).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    // set current index : check in panes collection length
    currentIndex = index;
    if(currentIndex < 0) currentIndex = ePanes.length-1;
    else if(currentIndex >= ePanes.length) currentIndex = 0;
    // display pane
    ePanes.eq(currentIndex).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    // menu selection
    $('.nav li').removeClass('current').eq(currentIndex).addClass('current');
}
// bind ul links
$('.nav li').click(function(ev){    showPane($(this).index());});
// bind previous & next links
$('.previous').click(function(){    showPane(currentIndex-1);});
$('.next').click(function(){    showPane(currentIndex+1);});
// apply start pane
showPane(0);
```

Comment: Great dmidz, Hurry, it this is working. Just one problem, when you click next and the after the third slide, it hides everything, how can i go to the first one, after third. the same for prev as-well.

Comment: instead of :
`currentIndex = Math.max(0, Math.min(ePanes.length-1, index));`
write something like :
`if(currentIndex < 0)  currentIndex = ePanes.length-1`
`else if(currentIndex >= ePanes.length)  currentIndex = 0`

Comment: Sorry can you please edit the above code. I have no idea, where this goes.